# Android Studio can't see the buttons

Tags: java, button

I created a new empty Android Studio project. I tried to put any button on the screen but nothing happened. Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using **constraint layout** in which case you'll have to set constraints to the button.

For starters, you can use

```
start_toStartOf="parent"
top_toTopOf="parent"
```